# jQuery and HTML 5 <audio>

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I have been playing around with HTML 5  tags combined with JS and jQuery to Build custom styled play/pause buttons. Its working pretty good so far the only problem is after you press play it takes a few seconds to load, Anyone know a way to simply display a "loading..."
message while the audio is loading?

Comment: Sure. Write some code.

Comment: What is your question?  How to manipulate the DOM?  How to set the text of an element?  How to handle a callback when the audio is ready?

Comment: sorry I realize this question is vague... :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for the "canplay" event. Have the page display "loading..." until this event occurs.

[Read more here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplay.asp).